# Stacking array slices (rbind for >2 dimensions)

Tags: r

I have a series of lapply calls that leaves me with a list of arrays.  The first dimension differs in number, and two of the dimensions are the same.  I want to place each 'row' (the first dimension) on top of each other, just like `rbind` would do for a 2d array (a matrix).

Data looks like this:

```
la <- list( array( dim=c(1,6,7) ), array( dim=c(2,6,7) ), array( dim=c(3,6,7) ) )
```

I can't use `do.call(rbind, la)` because it just flattens it to a matrix.

I could write something like:

```
rbind.array <- function(..., deparse.level=1) {
   allargs <- list(...)
   n <- length(allargs)
   dims <- sapply(la,dim)
   sel.dim <- which(!apply( dims, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))==1 ))
   stopifnot(length(sel.dim)==1)
   target.length <- apply( dims, 1, sum)[sel.dim]
   target.dims <- dims[,1]
   target.dims[sel.dim] <- target.length
   res <- array( dim=target.dims )
   for( i in seq(n) ) {
      # stack array slices one by one
   }
}
```

But surely such a function exists already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `abind` from **abind** does this...?

```
library(abind)
abind(la[[1]],la[[2]],la[[3]],along = 1)
```

In addition to the `Curry` solution, this appears to work as well:

```
do.call("abind",list(la,along = 1))
```

Comment: It does, thanks!  I used `do.call( Curry(abind, along=1), la )` to avoid having to type each one in.